# Is there a time system while selling items in Recettear?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

Recettear has a system of selling items based on bargaining - one thing that I have never quite understood though, is if you are timed during the bargaining part of the game, and if taking too much time to barter causes you to waste more time.

Is there any type of 'timing' involved in this part of the game, or do you just get a set number of customers?

Comment: My assumption is that the number of customers is determined first, but that's just gut feel.